# non-singular Toeplitz submatrices

Tags: recurrence-relations, hypergeometric-function, orthogonal-polynomials, symmetric-functions, toeplitz-matrices

Let $p(x) = (1+x+x^2)^d$ for $d\ge 2$ and call its coefficients
$$
p(x) = a_0 + a_1x+ a_2x^2 + \dots + a_{2d} x^{2d}.
$$
Let $T(d)$ be the infinite upper triangular and Toeplitz matrix defined as
$$
T(d)=\begin{pmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_{2d-1} & a_{2d} & 0 & 0 & \dots & &\\
0 &  a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_{2d-1} & a_{2d} & 0 & 0 & \dots &\\
0 & 0 &  a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \dots & a_{2d-1} & a_{2d} & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
& & &  \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &   & \ddots & \ddots & &\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for every $n\ge 1$ take the following submatrices:
$$
A_{d,n,1} = [T(d)]_{i=1:n}^{j=1:n}, \quad 
A_{d,n,2} = [T(d)]_{i=1:n}^{j=2:n+1}, \quad
A_{d,n,3} = [T(d)]_{i=1:n}^{j=3:n+2}, \quad \dots \quad 
A_{d,n,2d+1} = [T(d)]_{i=1:n}^{j=2d+1:n+2d},
$$
that are all the square submatrices you can extract from the first $n$ rows with consecutive columns and with non-zero diagonal.

> **Claim:**
>   $A_{d,n,k}$ is singular only for $k=2$ or $k=2d$ and the couples 
>   $$(d,n) = (4,3), (10, 8), (12,5)$$

We know a number of facts already, that are

- $det(A_{d,n,1}) = det(A_{d,n,2d+1}) = 1$
- $A_{2d,n,2d+1}$ are positive definite
- $det(A_{d,n,k})$ diverges to $+\infty$ with $n$ if $k$ is odd and $2<k<2d$

The claim is related to Schur symmetric polynomials (since we are working with Toeplitz matrices) and also it would mean that

- If $c_{n,d}$ is the n-th coefficient of the formal expansion of $$\frac 1{(1+x+x^2)^d} $$ then 
  $$ c_{n,d} = 0 \iff (d,n) = (4,3), (10, 8), (12,5)$$
- $$ \sum_{r=0}^n (-1)^k {d+r-1 \choose r}{r \choose n-r}=0 \iff (d,n) = (4,3), (10, 8), (12,5)$$
- $$\frac{\partial^n}{\partial x^n}\left[(1-x^2)^{\frac{n+d-1}2}\right]\Big|_{x=1/2} =0 \iff (d,n) = (4,3), (10, 8), (12,5) $$
- If  $c_n^{(\alpha)}(x)$ are the [Gegenbauer polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gegenbauer_polynomials), then $$c_n^d(\frac 12) = 0 \iff (d,n) = (4,3), (10, 8), (12,5)$$
- If  $P_n^{(\alpha,\beta)}(x)$ are the [Jacobi polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_polynomials), then $$P_n^{(-1/2,d-1/2)}(\frac 12) = 0 \iff (d,n) = (4,3), (10, 8), (12,5)$$
- If $ _2F_1(a,b,c,z)$ are the [Hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), then $$ _2F_1(-n,d+n,\frac 12,\frac 14) = 0 \iff (d,n) = (10, 4)$$
  $$_2F_1(-n,d+n+1,\frac 32,\frac 14) = 0 \iff (d,n) = (4,1), (12,2) $$
- Let $b_n^{(d)}$ be the recurrence sequence defined by $$b_0^{(d)} = 1, \quad b_1^{(d)}=d, \quad nb_n^{(d)} = (n+d-1)b_{n-1}^{(d)} - (n+2d-2)b_{n-2}^{(d)}.$$ Then
  $$b_n^{(d)} = 0 \iff (d,n) = (4,3), (10, 8), (12,5)$$

If you have  any insight on any of the above cited problems, please tell.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting problem, don't have much to add without spending more time, than that the generating function for your matrices $A_{d,n,k}=T_n(f_{d,n,k})$ are

$$
f_{d,n,k}(\theta)=e^{k\mathbf{i}\theta}\sum_{j=0}^{2d} {{d+1}\choose{j}}_2 e^{-j\mathbf{i}\theta}
$$

where ${{d+1}\choose{j}}_2$ is the entries of the trinomial triangle. Where does this problem come from?

Comment: It comes from the computation of Jordan forms. In particular, the rank of the above matrices determine the ranks of the powers of particular matrices.